# Generating function for the number of strings following a certain pattern.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Let $f_n$ denote the number of strings of length $n$ using letters $A,B,C$ and $D$ such that there are even number of $A's$; $1,2,3$  or $4 \ B's$; either $2$ or $5$ $C's$ and at least $1$ $D$.

So $f_0 = f_1 = f_2 = f3 = 0$, $f_4 = 12$ and $f_5 = 60$. To find the generating function for $f_n$.

---

I was trying to find a recurrence relation for $f_n$.

Its fine that there is at least one $D$.

But how to control how many $B's$ and $C's$ we have already used?

Comment: do you want to find recurrence or generating function ? I could not understand

Comment: @Bulbasaur can we find generating function without recurrence relation?

Comment: "can we find generating function without recurrence relation?" , i already answered your question by generating functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\color{blue}{\text{Generating Function:}}$

I think that [exponential generating functions](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/cgt_online/book/section03.02.html) is the best choice for your question.

- If there are even number of $A's$ , then E.G.F of $A$ is : $$1+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}+...+\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}+..=\frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$$
- E.G.F of $B's$ : $$\bigg(\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\bigg)$$
- E.G.F of $C's$ : $$\bigg(\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}\bigg)$$
- E.G.F of $D's$ : $$\bigg(\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+...\bigg)=(e^x -1)$$

For any desired $n$ find the coefficient of $x^n$ and multiply it by $n!$ [in the expansion of](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expanded+form+of+%28x+%2B+x%5E2+%2F2+%2Bx%5E3+%2F6+%2Bx%5E4+%2F24+%29%28x%5E2+%2F2+%2Bx%5E5+%2F120%29%28e%5Ex+-1%29%28%28e%5Ex+%2Be%5E%28-x%29%29%2F2%29) $$n![x^n]\bigg[\bigg(\frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}\bigg)(e^x -1)\bigg]$$

$\color{red}{\text{EXPANSION:}}$

[image: Expansion]

For example , for $n=5$  , $$5! \times \frac{1}{2}=60$$